# Removing item level mouseover effect in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, listitem

I am trying to remove the hover effect that brings up the checkbox next to the row item in SharePoint 2010 list item rows. Is there any settings that can make this happen? I would like to keep away from having to tinker with the CSS and javascripts. Please see illustration below. Thank you.

[image: Top row with mouseover.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no settings for that sort of thing - the selection check box is a default behavior. You are going to have to modify the CSS, for that.

Use SharePoint Designer (Available Here][1](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx)) to help determine whitch CSS elements control that behavior, and make a custom style sheet to override it.

Comment: Thanks EtherDragon! I was hopeful that there'd be some change that I can make to the webpart or the view that dispays the list without CSS tampering. I accidentally achieved that on one of my webparts, but don't know what I did to get that behavior. I never touched CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by going to the Modify View option of your list and unchecking the *Allow Individual Item Checkboxes* under Tabular View options.

Note: If you are using a Web Part to view it you might have to set the view again for the changes to reflect.